# Using a Radio-button to trigger the method

Tags: android, radiobuttonfor

Please help me on how I can use a radio-button to execute a method once radio button is checked, here is my code:

```
      if (RadioButton1.isChecked()){
                    UpdateResultsnewk();
                }else if (RadioButton2.isChecked()) {
                     UpdateResultsoldk();
                }


        public void UpdateResultsnewk(){
        int results1 = 100 + 10;
        Textview1.setText(results);

    }

 public void UpdateResultsoldk(){
    int results2 = 100 - 10;
    Textview2.setText(results);
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need:

```
yourRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if(checkedId == yourRadioButtonWhichShouldBeChecked.getId()) {
            yourMethodWhichShouldBeCalled();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm glad that I could helped you. Please mark this answer as solution then.